# Use re.findall in Python string to only find items that start with a capital letter?

Tags: python, python-re

If I have a Python string, how can I use re.findall to extract only the items that start with a capital letter?

My string looks like this:

```
my_string = ['a17b', 'Cupcake', '8ikl3', 'Dinosaur']
```

I want my extracted string to look like this:

```
new_string = ['Cupcake', 'Dinosaur']
```

Here's my code so far (not correct):

```
import re
new_string = re.findall(r'[^A-Z]', my_string)
```

Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Problem #1: `re.findall` takes a single `str`, you're passing it a `list` of `str`.

Comment: "If I have a Python string, how can I use re.findall to extract only the items that start with a capital letter?" You already know how to do this: by using the code that you tried to use. The problem is that **you don't** "have a Python string". You have a **list of** Python strings. This question is not really about regular expressions at all; it is about how to process a list.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `re`: just use `str.isupper`

```
[i for i in my_string if i[:1].isupper()]
```

Output:

```
['Cupcake', 'Dinosaur']
```

Comment: `str.istitle` requires *both* that it start with a capital letter *and* that all letters in a word following the capital letter be lowercase. That's the case for the OP's example, but it's slightly different from what they're describing. They may just want `if i[:1].isupper()` (the slice to `[:1]` means it silently discards the empty string instead of dying with an exception).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good point. Let me make edit

Comment: Wait, `istitle` is a thing? COOL

Comment: @YaakovBressler: Yep. There's also `.capitalize` and `.title` to convert strings to that casing style (`capitalize` operates on the string as a whole, `title` on each word in the string).

Answer (score 1):

That's not a string.  That's a list of strings.  You'll need something like:

```
newlst = [k for k in my_string if 'A' <= k[0] <= 'Z']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

my_string = ['a17b', 'Cupcake', '8ikl3', 'Dinosaur']
pattern = re.compile(r'^[A-Z]')
new_string = [i for i in my_string if pattern.match(i)] 
print(new_string)
```

Output:

> ['Cupcake', 'Dinosaur']

Answer (score 0):

##### Why it doesn't work:

- `findall()` searches a string, but you passed in a list of strings
- The expression `[^A-Z]` will return characters that are ***not*** in the range A-Z
- You want to copy the entire word, but you're only asking for the first letter

##### How to fix:

```
#join the list of strings to get yourself a string that will work with findall()

my_string = ['a17b', 'Cupcake', '8ikl3', 'Dinosaur']
my_string = ' '.join(my_string)

new_string = ['Cupcake', 'Dinosaur']

expression = r'[A-Z][\w]*'
#now re will find all words with capitalized first letters
new_string = re.findall(expression, my_string)

new_string
```

##### Decoding Expression ('[A-Z]\w*')

- `[A-Z]` finds Capitalized letters
- `\w` finds word characters
- `\*` tells re to look for 0 or more of the preceding term

One resource worth checking out is https://regex101.com